# What is Geometrical Probability?

Tags: probability, geometric-distribution, geometry, information-geometry

1. Is it a technique where Geometry is used to solve probabilistic problems?
2. Is it a kind of probability which grows Geometrically when we conduct experiments?
3. Is it a kind of distribution?

I am confused. Coz, my teacher is actually lecturing by mixing up all those three aforementioned items.

Also, I am not finding any book relevant to his lectures.

Comment: One could probably argue for any of those categories...without having the context that your teacher was presenting this material we cannot give you an answer. Why don't you ask your teacher?

Comment: Do you have a reference where this term comes up?  In general, geometric methods can be used to solve problems or illuminate concepts in any mathematical discipline.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_probability) clearly answers this question and provides references to books on the subject.

Comment: @MatthewDrury, https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxVqTx5Vp2gjYzlkUUF6YU1xTUU    

...................
..................

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxVqTx5Vp2gjUW5CdFpReVlzQ2s

Comment: Those links will eventually go dead, at which point this thread will not really be interpretable. Can you paste in whatever context is necessary to make this intelligible w/o the links? Otherwise, this should probably be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your reference, here's a representative use of the phrase *geometric probability*

> Let $\Omega = [0, 3]$ and let P be the geometrical probability on $\Omega$. Find the distribution function of the random variable
>
> {definition of a piecewise function}
>
> Is the distribution of X continuous (if so, find the relevant density)?

So it looks to me like they are using it to mean "the probability measure created by normalizing the area (or length or volume) measure".  For example, using the $\Omega$ in the above problem, the area (which is really length here) measure of an interval is

$$ \mu((a, b)) = b - a $$

but this makes the entire $\Omega$ have measure $3$, so we need to normalize, which creates the probability measure

$$ P((a, b)) = \frac{1}{3} \mu((a, b)) = \frac{1}{3} (b - a) $$

now $P(\Omega) = 1$, as we need to do probability.

I do not think this is a standard term, I have not heard it used this way before.  It does make some sense though.

Comment: (+1) You are correct, as the (very clear and rigorous) definition of "geometric model" on p. 6 of the second reference indicates.  The first reference appears to use "geometrical probability" as a synonym.  Clearly--by comparison to books with "geometric probability" in their titles and to the Wikipedia article--this is an idiosyncratic use of the phrase.